# Checkbox selection uisng Wrapper is not passed to controller

Tags: apex, visualforce, wrapper-class, inputcheckboxes

This might have been posted several times but i'm unable to workaround this issue using apex & I also looked at all the existing questions similar to this. I have a list of Opps with checkboxes in wrapper and i'm unable to retrieve the selections in apex where it always show false. we click on search button - searchaction() after selecting the checkboxes.Any help is really appreciated.
[image]

```
<apex:page controller="ForecastQuotaUpdateController" sidebar="false" docType="html-5.0">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pagemessages />
        <apex:pageblock >
            <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search by Acc/Owner/Parent..." title="Type in an Account Name"/>
            Year : &nbsp;
            <apex:inputField value="{!history.Year__c}"/>            
            User &nbsp;
            <apex:selectList multiselect="false" size="1" value="{!selectedUser}">
                <apex:selectOptions value="{!userOptionsList}"></apex:selectOptions>
            </apex:selectList>
            Team &nbsp;
            <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!isTeam}"/>            
            Confidence % &nbsp;
            <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!isOppConfidence}"/>            
            Exclude S1 &nbsp;
            <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!isS1Exclude}"/>
            Exclude S2 &nbsp;
            <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!isS2Exclude}"/>            
            Exclude S3 &nbsp;
            <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!isS3Exclude}"/>
            <apex:commandButton value="Search" action="{!searchAction}" status="status" rerender="formId"/>
        </apex:pageblock>
    </apex:form>

    <apex:form id="formId">
        <!-- List of Opps -->
        <div id="oppstblDiv">
            <table class="oppstbl" id="myTable">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="1" style="width:50px;">Select</th>
                        <th colspan="1">Opp Name</th>
                        <th colspan="1">Stage</th>
                        <th colspan="1">Budget</th>
                        <th colspan="1">Owner</th>
                        <th colspan="1">End Date</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <apex:repeat value="{!forecastOppWrapList}" var="oppWrap">
                        <tr>
                            <td><apex:inputCheckbox value="{!oppWrap.selected}"/></td>
                            <td>{!oppWrap.opp.Opportunity_Number__c}</td>
                            <td>{!oppWrap.opp.StageName}</td>
                            <td>{!oppWrap.opp.Budget__c}</td>
                            <td>{!oppWrap.opp.Owner.Name}</td>
                            <td>{!oppWrap.opp.End_Date__c}}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </apex:repeat>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>        
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Here's the controller

```
public class ForecastQuotaUpdateController {

    public String selectedUser { get; set; }
    public Boolean isTeam { get; set; }
    public Boolean isOppConfidence { get; set; }
    public Boolean isS1Exclude { get; set; }
    public Boolean isS2Exclude { get; set; }
    public Boolean isS3Exclude { get; set; }    
    public ForecastQuotaUpdateController(){
        isTeam = false;
        isOppConfidence = false;
        isS1Exclude = false;
        isS2Exclude = false;
        isS3Exclude = false;
        selectedUser = '';
        userOptionsList = new List<SelectOption>();
        userOptionsList.add(new SelectOption('', '--None--'));
        history = new Quota_History__c();
        yearCurrent = String.valueOf(System.Today().year());
        searchUtility('', yearCurrent,'', false, false, false, false, false, new List<ForecastOpportunityListWrapper>());
    }

    //Search Button
    public void searchAction(){
        List<SelectOption>  userOptionsListTemp = new List<SelectOption>();
        if(!userOptionsList.isEmpty()){
            userOptionsListTemp.addAll(userOptionsList);
        }
        if(history.year__c != null){        
            yearCurrent = history.year__c;
        }
        if(String.isBlank(selectedUser) && isTeam){
            ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.WARNING, 'Select a User'));        
        }
        else{    
            //Here i'm expecting "forecastOppWrapList" to have "selected" = true after selection on VFP (which isNOT working)
            searchUtility('', yearCurrent, selectedUser, isTeam, isOppConfidence, isS1Exclude, isS2Exclude, isS3Exclude, forecastOppWrapList); 
        }
        if(!userOptionsListTemp.isEmpty()){
            userOptionsList.clear();
            userOptionsList.addAll(userOptionsListTemp);
        }    
    }

    public void searchUtility(String AccountId, String yearStr, String sltUser, Boolean isTeamUser, Boolean isOppConfidenceSet, Boolean isS1ExcludeSet, Boolean isS2ExcludeSet, Boolean isS3ExcludeSet, List<ForecastOpportunityListWrapper> tempforecastOppWrapList){       
        for(Some accs query){
            ...
            ...
             //Opportunities List S1 S2 S3
            forecastOppWrapList = new List<ForecastOpportunityListWrapper>();
            for(Opportunity tempOpp : tempClosedWon.Values()){
                ForecastOpportunityListWrapper wrapOpp = new ForecastOpportunityListWrapper(tempOpp);
                forecastOppWrapList.add(wrapOpp);
            }
        }

        if(!tempforecastOppWrapList.isEmpty()){
            for(ForecastOpportunityListWrapper selectedOpp : tempforecastOppWrapList){
                if(selectedOpp.selected){
                    ...//Capture the selected opps logic
                }
            }
        }       
    }

   //Wrapper Class
    public List<ForecastOpportunityListWrapper> forecastOppWrapList { get; set; }
    public Class ForecastOpportunityListWrapper{
        public Id oppId { get; set; }
        public Opportunity opp {get; set;}
        public Boolean selected {get; set;}
        public ForecastOpportunityListWrapper(Opportunity o){
            opp = o;
            selected = false;
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Please always put even your one-line IF actions in brackets. Some Apple code broke because someone put a second line in an IF block and didn't put in brackets. It's best practice to put if{} brackets, no matter what. And it helps readability.

Comment: @DavidSchach Hi David, i updated the above code to reflect your recommendation. Can you please help me with the issue that i'm facing here?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a bit hard to follow. My guess is that this line and the following code:

```
forecastOppWrapList = new List<ForecastOpportunityListWrapper>();
```

is rebuilding the list (and so throwing away the `selected` flags) before you access the list in the following code.

Solutions:

- re-implement `searchUtility` would be best
- a quick fix would be to clone `forecastOppWrapList` if you really need both the posted (from the client) list and a newly created list in that method

Comment: Thanks for the response Keith. But i'm already kind of cloning the forecastOppWrapList in this line below
searchUtility('', yearCurrent, selectedUser, isTeam, isOppConfidence, isS1Exclude, isS2Exclude, isS3Exclude, forecastOppWrapList); 

which is nothing but the tempforecastOppWrapList which I then use to pull the selected Opps.

Comment: Yeah, not quite sure how Apex handles that; passing `forecastOppWrapList.clone()` would be a more clear-cut duplicate of the list.

Comment: Just tried that, still shows false

Comment: I ended up creating a separate method and separate button for this & which is working fine!

Comment: Glad you got it sorted @Sam.